# Shieldui - ASP.Net Core CRUD operations - popup editing

Tags: asp.net-core, shieldui

I am very new to shieldui. I am facing some problems with shieldui grid for asp.net core. Can anyone help me out in getting shieldui grid CRUD operations for asp.net core with all grid functionalities like filtering, sorting and grouping.
Please please anyone help me in this situation.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling to understand the ShieldUI set myself. I like the widgets, not so much the documentation. Anyways, after some hard work I am beginning to get an understanding of the workings of several widgets. I'm working with the grid myself. I have my grids working with remote data from an Api, including the sorting, paging etc. stuff of it. Your question is a bit broad though, what do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [this example](https://demos.shieldui.com/aspnetcore/grid-editing/editing-restful-web-service), and the other Grid editing examples in the same group?

They show how you can bind each of the CRUD operations to a remote API.